# Exclude js files in Task list Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Suddenly I see a hundred TODO item in my Task List from an AngularJs library. It is possible to filter out all .js files?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you can not do that, but you can filter by project or path.

[image: Screenshot]

Or, you can define your own custom tags and distinguish them by priority in the Task List, as described [in the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2.aspx).

Comment: Please paste the information from your links into your answer. Links may die over time, so preserve the information here.